# How to pickup 2 string on char on tag unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so this is literally bug on my game, when the player collides with the object there will change mesh with the index on it, whenever it collides with tag 10 on it the next one is 2, that should be 11 and so on.

look at my script :

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(other.gameObject.tag, "^(Cube|Sphere|Prism|[A-Z]|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30) "))    //If player collides with an obstacle
        {
            string indicatorCompareTag = "w";

            if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor)
            {
                indicatorCompareTag = playerMesh.mesh.name;
            }
            else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
            {
                indicatorCompareTag = gameObject.name + " Instance";
            }

            print("Player Mesh name : " + indicatorCompareTag);
            print("Collide tag name : " + other.transform.tag);

            print(playerMesh.mesh.name + " compare tag with " + other.transform.tag + " ? " + other.CompareTag(playerMesh.mesh.name));
            if (other.CompareTag(indicatorCompareTag))      //If the collided gameObject has the same mesh as the player
            {
                Camera.main.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
                for (int i = 0; i < meshes.Length; i++)
                {
                    print("Ganti");
                    if (meshes[i].name == other.transform.tag[0].ToString() || meshes[i].name== other.transform.tag.Substring(0).ToString())
                    {
                        score.isRighPath = true;
                        other.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
                        audio.play("SwithcedShape");
                        score.IncrementScore();
                        StartCoroutine(Hit());
                        playerMesh.mesh = meshes[i + 1];       //Changes the player's mesh
                        gameObject.name = meshes[i + 1].name;
                        if (indtX >= allAlphabets.Count)
                            indtX = 0;
                        else
                            indtX++;
                        Alphabetconfig();
                    }

                }
                GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
                //FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>().IncrementScore();      //Increments score
                //Plays Colides
            }
```

the problem i think  in this fuction, I've tried with substring but nothing changed its same

```
if (meshes[i].name == other.transform.tag[0].ToString() || meshes[i].name== other.transform.tag.Substring(0).ToString())
```

for change mesh with an index on it, there will change the mesh filter when the mesh name is the same as the tag.

```
 if (other.CompareTag(indicatorCompareTag))      //If the collided gameObject has the same mesh as the player
            {
                Camera.main.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
                for (int i = 0; i < meshes.Length; i++)
                {
                    print("Ganti");
                    if (meshes[i].name == other.transform.tag[0].ToString())
                    {
                        score.isRighPath = true;
                        other.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
                        audio.play("SwithcedShape");
                        score.IncrementScore();
                        StartCoroutine(Hit());
                        playerMesh.mesh = meshes[i + 1];       //Changes the player's mesh
                        gameObject.name = meshes[i + 1].name;
                        if (indtX >= allAlphabets.Count)
                            indtX = 0;
                        else
                            indtX++;
                        Alphabetconfig();
                    }

 public void Alphabetconfig()
    {
        activeAlphabets.Clear();
        for (int i = indtX; i <= indtX + 4; i++)
        {
            activeAlphabets.Add(allAlphabets[i]);
        }
    }
```

[enter link description here](https://media.giphy.com/media/igc7Q63Nj5oDVrjUBS/giphy.gif)

Comment: It's really unclear what the problem statement here is. Please describe the desired behaviour and then describe the behavior that is occurring now.

Comment: Why are you comparing tags to names?

Comment: @derHugo  just personal opinion, actually in my mind that will make easier but not that all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you want to archive. And I think the extensive use of tags and modifying gameobject names is not best practice.

From the description you gave this could be the error:
`meshes[i].name == other.transform.tag[0]`
This gives you only the first char of the tagname, so a `10` will be truncated to `1` and then incremented to `2` for the next mesh.

You may want to use `other.transform.tag` to work with the whole tagname or cut out the parts you don't need like this:

```
tagdigits = Regex.Replace(other.transform.tag, "[^0-9]", ""); // only digits remain
```